# Viper handle table cell action

Tags: swift, viper-architecture

What is the best way to handle cell action in Viper architecture? Here is my basic VC:

```
class StoriesViewController: BaseViewController {
    var presenter: StoriesPresenterInput?
    private var stories: [Story] = [] {
        didSet {
            guard let contentView = self.contentView as? StoriesView else { return }
            contentView.refresherControl.endRefreshing()
            contentView.activityView.stopAnimating()
            if stories.count == 0 {
                contentView.collectionView.setNoDataPlaceholder()
            } else {
                contentView.collectionView.removeNoDataPlaceholder()
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.presenter?.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
extension StoriesViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.stories.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "storiesCell", for: indexPath) as! StoriesCollectionViewCell
        cell.story = stories[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
```

In classic MVC, i would create a protocol for tap and delegate in my cell:

```
protocol StoryCellProtocol: class {
    func didTapUser(user: User)
}

class StoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
weak var delegate: StoryCellProtocol?
}
```

The set delegate to my VC in cellForRow:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

How to do the same thing in VIPER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMHO the best way would be to add the protocol conformance to your Presenter directly.**

`class StoriesPresenterInput: ..., StoryCellProtocol`

and assign the delegate in `cellForItem`:

`cell.delegate = presenter`

Since any user interaction should be parsed/processed in the presenter, you would also be effectively removing the (subjectively) redundant redirection between view and presenter.

Comment: Okay, i've created a viewModel for my Story and set delegate = self in presenter. But what if cell action only interact with VC itself? In my case VC has one AVPlayer instance which plays audio in current visible cell. Cell should interact with player for playback (slider to seek player). Can i create a protocol in cell and set delegate directly to VC?

Comment: Well, sure, but in VIPER View should be only responsible for visual representation and user action listening. Any logic/model update initiated by the user should be handled by Presenter/Interactor, and the resulting updates should be relayed to user via View. That being said, architectural decisions are not commandments.

Answer (score 0):

there is many good ways for that, assuming your input presenter is a protocol, a good one:   set to the protocol for the action in cell, for example, setup the protocol for the action cell:

```
    protocol CellAction {
          didAction()
    }
```

and configure your cell using  a method in your cell class like:

```
   func config(action: CellAction, story: Story) {
         //todo
   }
```

here is the tricky part, using your input to setting up the protocol to presenter, REMEMBER, ASUMING YOUR INPUT IS A PROTOCOL, using in cellForRow like:

```
      let cellAction = presenter as! CellAction
      cell.config(action: cellAction, story: story)
```

you need setup an extension for your presenter to set the protocol

```
  extension YourPresenter: CellAction {
         func didAction() {
          //todo
         }
   }
```